# How to target multiple forms: #form1, #form2, #form3

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to target several forms: #form1, #form2, #form3, and can't get it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = $('#form').val();
    target = (target.indexOf('#') === 0? target : '#' + target);

    $(target).validate({
        rules: {
            name  : { required: true },
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var options = { 
                target : target,
            };
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML
    .....

```
<form id="form1" action="order.php" method="post">.....</form>

<form id="form2" action="order.php" method="post">.....</form>
```

Comment: `$('#form1, #form2, #form3').validate({` is this you want ?

Comment: why do you need multiple forms? you can nest all your form elements under single form itself

Comment: @sravis Could help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form,#form1,#form2').each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert($(form).attr('id') + ' successful');
        }
    });
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/c5pzC/13/

Comment: I get why people imagine it would work directly with the $('id,id,id') version, since that's how so many plugins work... But I think the authors made the right decision here, since it's way less common to have multiple forms per page.  Instead, they return the validator object.

Comment: It keeps people on their toes... quickly weeds out anyone who is inexperienced with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to give these forms a class and target that class ? When you want to target several elements in a page that's usually the proper way.

HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="order.php" method="post" class="target-form">.....</form>
<form id="form2" action="order.php" method="post" class="target-form">.....</form>
```

JS

```
$('.target-form')
```

Comment: Any jQuery Validate plugin method **must** be wrapped inside the jQuery `.each()` method whenever more than one element is targeted by the selector. See [answer by Ryley](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333143/594235).